# How to combine the benefits of constants and symbols in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, symbols

currently I use constants for things like *task_type*:

```
class TaskType
    TWITTER_MENTION_REPLY = "twitter_mention_reply"
    TWITTER_FOLLOW = "twitter_follow"
    TWITTER_DM_REPLY = "twitter_dm_reply"
    TWITTER_RETWEET = "twitter_retweet"
end
```

so when I initialize a new task, I assign type like this:

```
new_task.task_type =  TaskType::TWITTER_MENTION_REPLY
```

the advantage of this approach is that in case the constant is typed incorrectly, the interpreter gives an error. The disadvantage is that comparing strings is costly, symbols are much better for that.
So the question is, how to combine these two benefits?

I tried to create the following class:

```
class TaskType
     TWITTER_MENTION_REPLY = :twitter_mention_reply
end
```

but the problem with it was that when saving it to db, the saved field looks like this: --:twitter_mention_reply

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord or any ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of symbols come from the symbol having an object identifier; that's the reason of a *O(1)* comparison between symbols. Strings are just different.

Your goals here are:

- Having a set of task types to choose from with TaskType::SOME_CONSTANT to choose from
- Save TaskType into a database
- Lowering the cost of comparison between task types

Since task type are stored in a database (along a model I suppose) I would take more care of what can optimize your SQL query than what can lower the cost of the comparison in Ruby.

My first choise would be using plain strings. Otherwise I would use integers, as they are well understood by any Ruby ORM and any database.

```
class TaskType
    TWITTER_MENTION_REPLY = 0
    ...
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for the detailed reply. What is the disadvantage of TWITTER_MENTION_REPLY = :twitter_mention_reply approach?

Comment: Pratically, symbols can't be mapped by ActiveRecord; symbols are not strings, `--:twitter_mention_reply` is a serialization of the given symbol. Philosophically, symbols represent something else, while in this case they represent only themself. Eventually, someone much more clever than me explains symbols here http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm :)

Answer (score 2):

Conversion to string before saving to db might help:

```
:twitter_mention_reply.to_s  # => "twitter_mention_reply"
# back to symbol
"twitter_mention_reply".to_sym  # => :twitter_mention_reply
```

Comment: So you suggest to use the TWITTER_MENTION_REPLY = :twitter_mention_reply method?

Comment: What is the cost of the string -> symbol / symbol -> string in Ruby?